# str_replace bug with foreach loop

Tags: php, jquery, html, chat

I've got a problem with my little text to smiley/emoji function in php, which is based on `str_replace`. This is my code.

```
$smileys = array( ":inlove:" => "/smileys/smiley2.png",
                      ":cool:" => "/smileys/smiley3.png",
                      ":tongue:" => "/smileys/smiley4.png",
                      ":wow:" => "/smileys/smiley5.png",
                      ":smile:" => "/smileys/smiley15.png",
                      ":happy:" => "/smileys/smiley6.png",
                      ":funny:" => "/smileys/smiley7.png",
                      ":wink:" => "/smileys/smiley8.png",
                      ":worried:" => "/smileys/smiley10.png",
                      ":pokerface:" => "/smileys/smiley9.png",
                      ":poop:" => "/smileys/smiley12.png",
                      ":thinking:" => "/smileys/35_thinking.png",
                      ":triumph:" => "/smileys/49_triumph.png",
                      ":vulcan:" => "/smileys/109_vulcan.png",
                      ":pointup:" => "/smileys/102_point_up_2.png",
                      ":santa:" => "/smileys/135_santa.png",
                      ":spy:" => "/smileys/134_spy.png");

if(isset($_POST['message'])) {
    $messagePlain = $_POST['message'];
    $messageSmileys = $messagePlain;

    foreach($smileys as $key => $img) {
        $messageSmileys = str_replace($key, '<img src="' . $img . '" />', $messageSmileys);
    }

    $connection->query(// Message to db);
}
```

It works fine. But the problem is, when the user inputs more than ~14 emojis in a row, the HTML gets destroyed and it looks like this:

[image]

And the HTML source like this:

```
<div class="media-body">
                            <h4 class="media-heading">test <small>07. August. 2017 01:34</small></h4>
                             <img src="/smileys/smiley2.png" /> <img src="/smileys/smiley3.png" /> <img src="/smileys/smiley5.png" /> <img src="/smileys/smiley4.png" /> <img src="/smileys/smiley15.png" /> <img src="/smileys/smiley6.png" /> <img src="/smileys/smiley7.png" /> <img src="/smileys/smiley8.png" /> <img src="/smileys/smiley10.png" /> <img src="/smileys/smiley9.png" /> <img src="/smileys/smiley12.png" /> <img src="/smileys/49_triumph.png" /> <img src="/smileys/109_vulcan.png" /> <img src="/smileys/102_point_up_2.p                            </div>
</div>
```

Could someone help me with this? Why is the HTML tag for `<img>` suddenly destroyed?

Comment: Oh wow. Looks like it's somewhere problematic with the way it is stored. Are you using any database? What's the storage size of the message in the DB? Looks like the truncation happens there.

Comment: Just realised the row where it's stored in the database (message) has the size of 500. I increased it and will test it now. #edit: Works fine now. Thank you!

Comment: Rather than `foreach($smileys` you can just do `str_replace(array_keys($smileys), array_values($smileys), $string);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your output:

```
<img src="/smileys/smiley2.png" /> <img src="/smileys/smiley3.png" /> <img src="/smileys/smiley5.png" /> <img src="/smileys/smiley4.png" /> <img src="/smileys/smiley15.png" /> <img src="/smileys/smiley6.png" /> <img src="/smileys/smiley7.png" /> <img src="/smileys/smiley8.png" /> <img src="/smileys/smiley10.png" /> <img src="/smileys/smiley9.png" /> <img src="/smileys/smiley12.png" /> <img src="/smileys/49_triumph.png" /> <img src="/smileys/109_vulcan.png" /> <img src="/smileys/102_point_up_2.p
```

The above string's length is `499` characters. I strongly believe that your `message` field in the database table is limited to 500 characters or something and the output is truncated to those bits.

**Solution / Suggestion**

If you are using MySQL Database Server, I would strongly recommend you changing the database type from `VARCHAR(500)` to `TEXT` or `LONGTEXT`.

Comment: Do you mean “believe” rather than “doubt”?

Comment: @Ryan I am confident this would be the cause.

Comment: @Ryan Rewriting an answer with a solution.

Comment: @Ryan Check the message from the OP. Looks like that was it. We both were right.

Comment: I increased it and it worked, thanks to @PraveenKumar

Comment: @Aarvx Don't increase it, use the `TEXT` or `LONGTEXT`.

Answer (score 1):

Your database field probably has a length limit. You might want to raise that, but there’s a more important initial fix: store the original text in the database and perform the replacements on the output instead.

This is especially important because it looks like you’re probably vulnerable to HTML injection right now. Make sure to run [`htmlspecialchars`](https://php.net/htmlspecialchars) before doing the replacement and be aware of how you need to encode your output to make it safe. [How to prevent XSS with HTML/PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php) might be a good start.